# curl_setopt returns empty array in middle

Tags: php, curl

```
function fz_json_api_get($results) {

    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, FALSE);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $results);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-Type: application/json'));
    $result = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);

    $result = json_decode($result, true);

    if(empty($result)){
        echo 'Problem in getting feed data';
        return ;
    }

    return $result;
}
```

This function working good but stops in middle after 15th page and error is not in json coz it's opening good on browser.

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.curl-error.php

Comment: Following the answer of @MichaelBerkowski maybe you need to configure the apache, with the display_errors parameter (I don´t know exactly if it is apache setting, it is on php.ini)

Comment: I tried adding if(curl_error($ch)) { echo 'error:' . curl_error($ch); } before curl_close ($ch) and also set set_time_limit(0); on script but still it didn't shows any error. So still script stops in middle when trying to fetch the json page.